# Send multiple emails with different attachments each

Tags: python

I have a list of text files and html files generated by two distinct functions. Each file is labeled signal1.txt, signal2, etc. and signal1.html, signal2.html, etc. I need to send an email with each file pair (signal1.txt and signal1.html, signal2.txt and signal.2.html, and so forth). I've tried several different ways, but I keep getting just one file pair attached (the last file number whatever it is). I have no problem sending one file type, but it gets messy when I try with two different files.

Any help is appreciated. The code is as follows.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
import smtplib, ssl
import os

dirname = r'C:\Path\To\Files'
ext = ('.txt','html')

for files in os.scandir(dirname):
    if files.path.endswith(ext):

        def sendmail():
            html_body = '''
            <html>
                <body>
                    <p style="font-size: 12;"> <strong>Alert</strong><br>{html}</p>
                </body>
            </html>
            '''.format(html=html)

            subject = f'Text file content'
            senders_email = 'mail@mail.com'
            receiver_email = 'mail@mail.com'

            # Create a multipart message and set headers
            message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            message['From'] = senders_email
            message['To'] = receiver_email
            message['Subject'] = subject

            #Attach email body
            message.attach(MIMEText(html_body, 'html'))

            # Name of the file to be attached
            filename = f'signal.html'

            # Open file in binary mode
            with open(filename, 'rb') as attachment:
                # Add file as application/octet-stream
                part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
                part.set_payload(attachment.read())

            # Encodes file in ASCII characters to send via email
            encoders.encode_base64(part)

            # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
            part.add_header(
                'Content-Disposition',
                f"attachment; filename= {filename}",

            )

            # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
            message.attach(part)
            text = message.as_string()

            # Log into server using secure connection
            context = ssl.create_default_context()
            with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.com", 25) as server:
                # server.starttls(context=context)
                # server.login(senders_email, 'password')
                server.sendmail(senders_email, receiver_email, text)
            print("Email sent!")
        sendmail()
```

Comment: `def sendmail` would be better above the for loop, and ideally should take as arguments the pair of files to attach. At the moment, you have the filename hard-coded.

Comment: @DobbyTheElf Hey, thanks for your input. But if I put the email function above the for loop, how can I iterate over the files?

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted [one of these examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) for your problem. This puts all the files in one email:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function.
import smtplib

# Here are the email package modules we'll need.
from email.message import EmailMessage

import os

dirname = 'C:\Path\To\Files'
ext = ('.txt','html')

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Text file content'
msg['From'] = 'mail@mail.com'
msg['To'] = 'mail@mail.com'

# Open the files in binary mode.  You can also omit the subtype
# if you want MIMEImage to guess it.
for filename in os.scandir(dirname):
    if filename.path.endswith(ext):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            data = fp.read()
            msg.add_attachment(data)

# Send the email via our own SMTP server.
with smtplib.SMTP('localhost') as s:
    s.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: Nice, gonna test it and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Found a way that worked using glob.

```
dirname = r'C:\Path\To\Files'
regex = create_txt_files(event_dict)
html_file = create_html_files(event_dict)

signalfiles = sorted(list(pathlib.Path(dirname).glob('*.txt')))
htmlfiles = sorted(list(pathlib.Path(dirname).glob('*.html')))

for i, path_html_file in enumerate(htmlfiles):
   sendmail(html_file[i], regex[i], path_html_file)
```